# Is "MOV DWORD ptr ds:[ECX], ECX" equivalent to "MOV DWORD ptr ds:ECX, ECX"

Tags: arrays, pointers, assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

If *ECX* holds a pointer to a structure or an array, is `MOV DWORD ptr ds:[ECX], ECX` equivalent to `MOV DWORD ptr ds:ECX, ECX`

I have attached this image:

[image]

When I first saw that line, it got me to think, in the high level language context if it is indeed:

1) a pointer to a function which does nothing at all, but calls itself, thus achieving recursion instead.

2) an array/structure of x datatype whose first index is a pointer to the array/structure itself OR the structure/array's first entry. **And hence my question in the title**.

Other than that it seems to me pretty arbitrary: (an address storing the value of the said address which happens the address itself?). Any thought on that?

Comment: If you can't take the time to copy some text *as text* into your question, I'm not taking the time to read more than the question title.  `mov dword ptr [ecx], ecx` is a store.  `mov ecx,ecx` is a reg-reg move, and is a no-op since it moves ecx to itself.  `MOV DWORD ptr ds:ECX, ECX` is probably a syntax error.

Comment: @Peter, "If you can't take the time to copy some text as text into your question, I'm not taking the time to read more than the question title" ------

If you don't even bother to click to see the content of the asker, what is the point answering? Not all questions are meant for people like you, but for those who are interested in helping the asker. Unnecessary comment doesn't help anyone. let's keep thins professional!!!! There is a context given in the assembly code in the image. Beside IT IS AN IMAGE. So copying is out of the question.

Comment: Arean, Peter is correct. Please paste the text of your code into your question.

Comment: The question title seemed specific enough.  The rest of your question seems to have no connection to it, though.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I also want to know the rest of what i said in question cos there is a character limit on the title that I can't fit everything in the title.

Comment: @PeterCordes answered your question. You should be able to figure out the answers to the two questions you post in the bottom of your question based on that.

Comment: I had a quick look at the code in the image. To me, it seems like variables of one structure are copied to another structure. But the way it's done looks strange. For example: The first `MOV EDI, EDI` serves no purpose. It's a valid instruction, but does nothing. Neither an alignment, nor setting `EFLAG`s which could be tested. And I doubt that this is obfuscated code, because the rest doesn't look like that.

Comment: @zx485  "The first 'MOV EDI, EDI' serves no purpose" ----- Maybe this is the beginning of a function call in win dll? I think it does. ECX itself is a reference to a structure with 3 members, I guess, because whatever value EAX+4 contains is being copied as reference into member fields of ECX (ie; ECX, ECX+4, ECX+C).      What bothered me most is why  mov dword ptr ds;[ecx],ecx?  It is sort of saying the very first member of the structure is storing a reference to the structure itself. I can't imagine the purpose in high level context. Seems suspicious to me.

Comment: 'It is sort of saying the very first member of the structure is storing a reference to the structure itself.'. Yes, that is the purpose of `MOV dword ptr [ECX], ECX`. I could only speculate about the reason why this should be done. Maybe _this_ is some kind of anti-debugging technique ensuring that a given instance of a class is located at this specific address. IDK.

Comment: `MOV EDI, EDI` is [explained by Microsoft](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110921-00/?p=9583) . It is there for the purpose of hotpatching.

Answer (score 1):

Under MASM `MOV DWORD ptr ds:[ECX], ECX` is not equivalent to `MOV DWORD ptr ds:ECX, ECX` because the former is syntactically valid while the later is not.

As for your other questions:

1) If a function pointer is stored in ECX then this instruction would modify the function, which generally isn't permitted under most operating systems and so cause a crash. Even the write were allowed it would change the instruction or instructions at the start of function that when executed wouldn't do anything useful and probably crash. It would never result in recursion.

2) Probably something like this.

It doesn't look arbitrary to me.